# how to use video memory as standard memory storage?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I would use video memory on video board (256mb) as a standard memory for storing random values. I know very little about video graphics but i know that one approach is to just make 'models' or other video graphics objects storing my values, thus the video board thinks it processes video images or something this way. But is there another approach?

good article is http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Using_Graphics_Card_Memory_as_Swap
that how linux has implemented it. Looks like i need to write windows device driver for graphics subsystem to access video memory.

MS resource about video memory: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmulcahy/archive/2009/02/11/windows-and-video-memory.aspx

Comment: Why do you think you need it?

Comment: @Kirill, because it just exist

Comment: if your only alternative to video RAM would be to use disk, then it might be worth considering. Likewise, if you want to do it so you can move some of your computation to the GPU, that can *definitely* be worthwhile. Trying to do it just because it's there, however, is going to be a lot of work for minimal return.

Comment: @Jerry, most modern video cards supports upto 1gb video memory that is just wasted when no directX/opengl applications is run. So my motivation is to use it when it is not used. For example for paging file. Look at the link in the my first post.

Comment: So why it is not a good store about minimal security?

Answer (score 6):

This is a worse idea than you can possibly comprehend, but sure, you can always allocate a texture with DirectX and set it to be put in video memory only, write stuff in it, then at some later time lock it and read your data back out.

Good luck achieving a fifth of the speed you would by using normal system memory however.

Comment: @Blindy, yes, i think about it but dont know it is poor performance. dont it run at high speed? or the video api makes it slower?

Comment: Because that's simply not how graphics cards are made to be used. They are very, very powerful devices, but for only a handful of very specific usage patterns. Locking the video memory and forcing it to work in step with the CPU is the absolute worst way you can interact with the GPU.

Comment: LOL at "a fifth of the speed". Good luck getting it to a 1/25 of the speed!

Comment: You never know what monster of a GPU he has, considering his weird non-conventional memory fetish he's displayed in his previous questions.

Comment: Okay, but look at the link i provided in first post. It is incomplete but says i can map/access video memory just by using high addresses.

Comment: That's for the old VGA direct memory access under real-time systems (DOS) circa 1990. Fast forward 21 years and you get to the present where my answer is true. Besides back then video memory (which was actually system memory) was a couple of kb, nothing to get excited over!

Comment: @Blindy, that is linux doing this : http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Using_Graphics_Card_Memory_as_Swap

Comment: Also it says it is fast. Of course gentoo developers will not use it for swap or ramdisk if it is 1/25 or fifth of the speed. So looks like i need to create windows driver to access to video memory.

Comment: Does it? All I see in your article is "Unlike motherboard RAM and hard drives, there aren't any known video cards that have ECC memory. This may not be a big deal for graphics rendering, but you definitely don't want to put critical data in it or use this feature on servers."

Comment: Ok @Blindy, if were will run this project.

Comment: GPUs are stream processing devices. They're bad at anything that can't be set up as an uninterrupted stream of computations. They're MIMD devices where it takes A LOT of time to start the process, but the process itself is very fast.